# Access from Java to Tomcat paths

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, path

I have a webapp running in my local Tomcat. The path is: `tomcat/webapps/myproject`.
I have some resources in this project all in a folder with this path: `tomcat/webapps/myproject/resources`

So, I am trying to acces to this resources from a Java project, using a file `config.properties`. In this file I have something like this:

```
tomcat.url= http://localhost
tomcat.port=8080
tomcat.resources=/myproject/resources
```

I tryed also different combinations of `/` or `\` but I get this error running my project:

```
Trying to acces to a directory that does not exist
```

My Java code:

```
Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("config.properties");    
String sourcePath = config.getString("tomcat.resources");
//And I try to list this folder  
File dir = new File(sourcePath);
String[] children = dir.list();         
if (children == null) {          
    // Either dir does not exist or is not a directory
    throw new ServiceExecutionException("Trying to generate Metadata in a directory that does not exist");                  
}
```

I don't know what is wrong, in projects I made before, simliar to this, I had something similar and it found everything.
Any ideas?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I rephrase my question. Where do you save your Java code? Basically what is the folder structure of your webapp.

Comment: The project where I want to do this, just provides services to my webapp project. But is it really meanfull?? I mean, I am connecting to my localhost in config.properties, am I right? Thanks for your commnents and answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>the file must be located at `tomcat/webapps/myproject/src/main/resources`</strike> Check update.

I don't know how you are accessing the file, but just in case I'd recommend you to use [PropertiesConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html)

```
 private static final String CONFIGURATION_PATH = "config.properties";
 PropertiesConfiguration configuration = new PropertiesConfiguration(CONFIGURATION_PATH);
```

**Edited**

The problem is that you are trying to open a file located (keeping in mind that "/" is your root file system) at `/myproject/resources` when your file is located at (probably) `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/myproject/resources`.

You can get the real path of your file using [ServletContext#getRealPath](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

Comment: Yes, I am doing this. But in tomcat/webapps/myproject there is not src, just folders as pages, styles...

Comment: but that is exactly what I want to avoid, absoulte paths as /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/myproject/resources. I want to get this resources via localhost or other host, to don't depend on the machine. Thanks

Comment: That's why you should use `ServletContext#getRealPath` so you don't depend on the machine!