# Get Physical Path by Server Path in Tomcat

Tags: java, file, tomcat, path

I have a server path of a file and I want to delete that file in server side code, but `fileNotFound` exception is thrown, so I think I need physical corresponding path of the server path of a file.

How do i get physical path of a file by its http path? 
in ASP.NET `Server.MapPath("../images/myImage.png")` - would have worked, but i'm in **JAVA**

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3879829/180100

Comment: `System.getProperty("catalina.home")` should get you the folder where Tomcat is installed. I understand your path is relative to that location.